# ASP.NET and WCF Session

Tags: asp.net, wcf

We have WCF based SOA architecture and ASP.NET web application consume the services hosted. Within each method that needs service call, we create a proxy instance and close when the results are returned. The binding is basicHttpBinding.  By default InstanceContextMode is per session, do we need to change this to Percall as we do not require any state full calls in the application. Does this improve any performance?

Comment: Yes, quite possibly. Since you don't need to worry about the whole session overhead, calls should be a bit faster.